# How to log in on Fedora 22 Cloud image running on VirtualBox

Tags: virtual-machine, fedora, cloud

I've just downloaded a Fedora 22 Cloud image and ran it on VirtualBox under Windows, everything works pretty well, except that it asks me for a username/password. The problem is that every place I've read so far says the default is "fedora" and no password, but it won't let me login. I've also noticed that a service called cloud-init is responsible for setting up the cloud image, the login credentials, etc, but since this image is not running on a real provider (the server is just a VM running on a server in my room) I don't know what to do. It's the first time I work with Cloud images and I chose it because I just need a lightweight OS to stand on a VM to run very few and simple web apps for myself, and because Fedora no longer provides an installation DVD to choose the minimal installation.

Comment: Which exact image are you using?  Can you boot in single user mode and set a password there?

Comment: The image is the RAW (.raw) image you download from the official fedoraproject.org download site.

Comment: I'm not sure these cloud images will be as convenient as hoped.  Even the raw image's `cloud-init` still  tries EC2's service, etc.  You could create your own `meta-data` and `user-data` files [as described in the documentation](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/datasources.html#no-cloud), but that doesn't look super convenient either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's *a* way to get the Fedora 22 Cloud image to work with `cloud-init` on VirtualBox (method borrowed heavily from [Cloud-Init docs](http://cloudinit.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/datasources.html#no-cloud)).

First generate an ISO with minimal `meta-data` and `user-data` files:

```
$ { echo instance-id: iid-local01; echo local-hostname: f22-cloud; } > meta-data
$ printf "#cloud-config\npassword: fedora\nchpasswd: { expire: False }\nssh_pwauth: True\n" > user-data
$ genisoimage  -output seed.iso -volid cidata -joliet -rock user-data meta-data
```

Then assign your generated ISO to your VirtualBox guest's CD drive and un-check it from the boot-order selection (you still need to boot from the F22 image).

Start your virtual machine.  You can login with username "fedora" and password "fedora" (without the quotes of course).  After login, you can `sudo su -` if you wish to become root user.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try it as soon as I get to the office.

Comment: I'll have to refer you to the Fedora docs for some comparisons.  I'm new to them as well and have just been poking around and browsing to see what is included.  Things I've noted so far:  1) `cloud-init` is highly configurable so you may want to expand what your ISO holds; 2) F22 repos have a temporary checksum issue preventing some package installs/updates.  I also wonder if a minimal system ISO/image might be easier for some use cases so that no `cloud-init` headbanging need be done.

Comment: I in fact installed the server version with a minimal install setting when I gave up with the cloud version, but still, your suggested answer is correct. I've got it working. Thank you.

Comment: You may also want to try the [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) image Fedora Cloud provides starting with F22. This uses the vagrant conventions of a user account with name and password of `vagrant`.